# Is it possible to add nofollow to link to https://www.y.com/uk/practice/eye_care in this code for embedding?

Tags: html

```
<div id="06lv225f"></div><script src="https://www.y.com/get-script?widget_container_id=06lv225f&type=y-list-widget&tenant=athena-uk&language=en&profileType=practice&layoutType=WF_LIST_A&slugs=eye_care&background=transparent&itemBackground=ffffff&itemFrame=true&linkUrl=https://www.y.com/uk/practice/eye_care"></script>
```

Please explain why

Thanks in advance!

I've emailed a friend - I don't know HTML / Javascript

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add nofollow to this code for embedding?

No.

> Please explain why

It isn't a link.

Comment: Thanks! I was referring to the link to https://www.y.com/uk/practice/eye_care in the code

Comment: @ChrisB — That URL is not in a link, it is the source of a script (on a domain that returns server not found error).

Comment: I've just used a sample domain for this example - I know the domain doesn't exist